# Ktor route parameter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am developing a project with Ktor and I have encountered an issue. The problem involves passing a "queryParameter" as a function parameter so that I don't have to check it for every endpoint of the underlying routes. Do you know if this can be done?

```
route("{clientID}"){
 val clientID = call.request.queryParameters["clientID"]?.toIntOrNull()
 if (clientID != null) {
    //sub route with clientID
    userApi(clientID)
    ....
 }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Of course, I tried making the call as if I were inside an endpoint, but the "Route" class does not have the "call" variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve the problem that way because the routing initialization and the call happen at different times. The former occurs on the server startup, and the latter occurs on every HTTP request.

You can write a plugin to minimize the code duplication:

```
val plugin = createRouteScopedPlugin("plugin") {
    onCall { call ->
        if (call.clientID() == null) call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    }
}

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 4444) {
        routing {
            route("{clientID}") {
                install(plugin)
                userApi()
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

fun Route.userApi() {
    get("/user") {
        call.respondText { call.clientID().toString() }
    }
}

fun ApplicationCall.clientID(): Int? = request.queryParameters["clientID"]?.toIntOrNull()
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I was hoping there was a way. It could be interesting to avoid duplicating the code, but above all, to be closer to the SOLID principle.